# AWS lambda SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I've followed the guide from serverless-stack.com and divided my api up in multiple services in one mono repo. 
The code deploys fine with seed.run but when I try to reach some of the endpoints from my reactjs webclient, if gets an error from my api.

I've tried to console.log the error, but it dosen't reveals more details. I guess from other questions here at stackowerflow that it might be related to ES6 or babel, but I'am not sure.

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": ["source-map-support", "transform-runtime"],
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "node": "8.10" }],
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

I receive the following error at AWS (cloudwatch):

```
Syntax error in module 'list': SyntaxError
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18) .
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

UPDATED:

My babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
      [
          "env",
          {
              "targets": {
                  "node": "8.1"
              }
          }
      ]
  ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.1.4",
  "description": "Backend API for APP.",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.224.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.18.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.18",
    "stripe": "^5.8.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try passing the `modules: "commonjs"` option to the env preset. That should let you use ES6 modules and have them work in node.

Comment: Hi, can you please guide me some more? Where do I set this, in package.json?

Comment: Like this? {
  "plugins": ["source-map-support", "transform-runtime"],
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "node": "8.10", "modules": "commonjs"} ],
    "stage-3"
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Import syntax is not available in Node v8.x.x. Use **require** instead, or compile it with babel, just like Bogdan Alexandru Militaru did.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to deploy my code to lambda function running Node 8.1, using Babel version 6. I had exacty the same problem as you mention above. The solution for me:

### `.babelrc` file

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "8.1"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

### Dev dependencies from `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1"
  },
```

### Scripts from `package.json`

```
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && babel ./lambda/custom/ -d dist && cp lambda/custom/package.json dist/",
    "start": "nodemon",
    "serveo": "ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net",
    "deploy": "npm run build && ask deploy",
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that dosen't seem to work for me. I've updated my post with the new babelrc, webpack and package.json files.

Comment: I suggest you to simply build locally and to take a look at how that code is formatted. There seems to be a problem in `module 'list'`, probably a strange import. It's strange because you don't have an error from the beginning in index.js, or there you don't have any `import * as XYZ from something`? Can you try to put there an unused import just for testing?

I can take a look with you at your code, but I cannot find any contact info in your profile. Or if you can post more info's about how do you make this export `import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib"`.

Comment: Hi. How do I build it locally? I have only found a way to invoke the functions local? https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local/ I've tried to remove my imports from the list.js file, and now the error is at the next line: export async function main(event, context) { you can contact my at tstarkdk@gmail.com if you would like to contact me.

Comment: Can you try to take a look at my [github repo](https://github.com/boobo94/alexa-starter-pack), I use `ask cli` for deployment, but not that's part is important here. Try to put the command `"build": "babel ./PROJECT_PATH -d dist"` so your project will be transpiled into a folder called `dist` in the root. Then you can take a look at your code. Let me know how is going, if not we can have a chat.

Comment: I use seed for deployment to AWS. I'am not quite sure how to use the build command in my package.json? I have my repo at gitlab, maybe I can invite you to it, so you can see it, if you have a user there?

Comment: Sure. my username is `boobo94`